# How do I set up grunt-mocha to error on global leaks?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, gruntjs

I cannot seem to figure out how to set up grunt-mocha to produce a warning or error when a code under test globally leaks an object.  When testing in the browser, I noticed that I had some global leaks.  However, when I subsequently ran my test suite via grunt no leaks were reported.

I have tried several things to resolve this problem.  First, I tried setting up my "mocha" task in my grunt.js file as follows based on [syntax found on the grunt-mocha GitHub page](https://github.com/kmiyashiro/grunt-mocha)

```
mocha: {
  all: {
    src: ['test/**/*.html'],
    options: {
      ignoreLeaks: false
    }
  }
```

When that didn't work, I tried to manually change the value in the grunt-mocha code within my node_modules directory to `false`.  That had no effect but along the way I discovered that grunt-mocha works by writing out test results to a temporary file and then reading them in and reporting the results.  I disabled the portion of the code that deletes the temporary file and examined it.  It does not appear to contain any errors corresponding to the global leaks.

Finally, I tried to compare grunt-mocha's test reporter to Mocha's built-in "spec" reporter to see if perhaps some portion of the reporting interface was not implemented or something like that.  I have not seen anything obvious that would suggest that global leaks wouldn't be reported since, from what I can tell, they are reported as normal errors.

I originally selected grunt-mocha as it is what the [Yeoman project](http://yeoman.io/) chose for its test task.  In addition, the other projects I've seen that run Mocha from grunt appear to be more focused on native Mocha testing (e.g., for Node.js development) than browser development.

Having the leaks reported in the browser is fine for now as I will generally be making changes to my code and refreshing the browser during development.  However, I want to ultimately use a continuous integration server to run the test suite.  Any help straightening this out is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Currently, ignoreLeaks is not a supported mocha feature in `grunt-mocha`. It shouldn't be too hard to add, I'll look into it.